# Run multiple tests with Selenium DataProvider

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist, testng, dataprovider

I am currently using testng + selenium to automate my tests, and I have the following scenario:

I need to read from an excel file, transform each row in an object and run 1 test for each of them. I am trying to use annotation @DataProvider to return an Array of objects, however it is only able to return Iterators and Objects[][]. Is there any workaround I can use to return an array of Cliente objects from the DataProvider? I have tried the following code, however it only prints the data from Client2:

```
public class TestDataProvider 
{
    Cliente cliente;

    @DataProvider(name = "test1")
    public static Object[][] dataMethod() {     
        return new Object[][] { { new Cliente("Client1", "1111111111") },
                                { new Cliente("Client2", "2222222222") }};
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test1")
    public void testMethod(Cliente cliente) {
        System.out.println(cliente.getNome() + " " + cliente.getCartao());
    }
}
```

Edit1: Cliente class:

```
public class Cliente {
    private static String name;
    private static String card;

    //Construtor method
    public Cliente(String name, String card){
        setname(name);
        setCartao(card);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Cliente.name = name;
    }

    public String getCard() {
        return card;
    }

    public void setCard(String card) {
        Cliente.card = card;
    }
}
```

Values that are printed in the console:

```
Client2 2222222222
Client2 2222222222
```

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet of Cliente class so that it would be easier for anyone who is providing the answer.

Comment: Why do you want array of Cliente objects? TestNG iterates array of Cliente objetcs and calls your Test method for each Cliente object. Why do you want to iterate yourselves?

Comment: Thanks guys for answering, I have added the code of the Cliente Class.

CARE, I am trying to return an array of Cliente objects, as I will read each of the objects and run a Test for each of them. Do you mean that this is not necessary? If so, would you have an example of how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If skip some mistakes in names your example should work.

Answer (score 3):

So...

Your prerequisites:

- excel file, each row - one dataset
- run test for each dataset

What can you do:

1. Create `@DataProvider` which return `Iterator<Object[]>` with your datasets where each Object[] is your row from excel. (the easiest one)
2. Use `@Factory` to manually iterate through your datasets and call test methods.
3. Use `@DataProvider` to provide data for `@Factory` and do as above. 
   The 2nd and 3rd options are complicated, but have some benefits if you has other parameters, except datasets, to run tests.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the help. With RocketRacoon's third suggestion I managed to resolve my problem. Below is a simple example:

```
public class ProvidedTest 
{
    private static nome;
    private static cpf;
    private static cartao;

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {     
        return new Object[][] { {"Client1", "111111111", "444444444"},
                                {"Client2", "222222222", "555555555"},
                                {"Client3", "333333333", "666666666"}};

    }

    @Factory (dataProvider="dataProviderMethod")
    public ProvidedTest(String nome, String cpf, String cartao){        
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.cartao = cartao;

    }

    @Test
    public void testCase(){
        System.out.println(cliente.getNome());
        System.out.println(cliente.getCpf());
        System.out.println(cliente.getCartao());
    }
}
```