# can i send arguments to the @DataProvider annotation method in testng

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, dataprovider

I am trying to send arguments to @DataProvider annotation method, How it can be achived?? if it is possible how it is possoible please let me know

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747834/run-multiple-tests-with-selenium-dataprovider)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run multiple tests with Selenium DataProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747834/run-multiple-tests-with-selenium-dataprovider)

Comment: Elaborate your question with more details, What exactly you wants to pass as argument and for what, where do you want to achieve it.