# Using Data Providers with an Excel datasheet

Tags: java

I'm a newbie and I have a question about selenium using Data Providers with an Excel datasheet.
Can anyone tell me how to handle this, please?
I'm using Eclipse and selenium to test new functionality for a web application, currently, I have a problem
When the addition is successful, the system displays a popup and in case there is no mandatory field, it is notified by a command right next to the input field. so I do not know how to write code to handle this place to get a message that can satisfy both cases above with the purpose of using parameters to transmit data.
Thank you very much

Comment: Hello, Alice! Hope you're doing well, and welcome to StackOverflow! You'll get better answers to your question if you show us your code and explain what you've tried and how it failed, as well as how other ways that you've researched to solve the problem failed to help you. You can see an explanation on how to ask here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run multiple tests with Selenium DataProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747834/run-multiple-tests-with-selenium-dataprovider)